# Simulate click on link via anchor link

Tags: javascript, html

I feel like I'm trying to achieve something relatively simple but the solutions I came up with seemed rather complex so I wanna double check.

I have a simple navigation on a static website composed of different `a` tags that each link to some other pages on that site, except for **one**! That one `a` tag is special as it has no `href` but some special attribute (e.g. `blabla-data-link`). This opens a third-party overlay. It doesn't matter on which page I'm on. The overlay is always opened on the current page when clicking the link in the navigation.

Now I would like to create a link that opens the overlay after loading a page. E.g. `example.com/#something`. How can I do this?

The only idea I currently have is the following: Hide the `a` tag of the third-party overlay. Create another visible link with an anchor (`#something`). On each page load, check if the current url has the anchor. If yes, simulate click on the hidden `a` tag. If no, do nothing. If the visible link in the navigation is clicked, simulate a click on the hidden `a` tag, as well.

```html
<a class="blabla-overlay" style="display: none;" blabla-data-link="123abc"></a>
<a class="blabla-link" href="#something">Click me for overlay!</a>

<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    if (window.location.hash === '#something') {
      openBlaBlaOverlay();
    }
  });

  document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (event.target.matches('.blabla-link')) {
      event.preventDefault();
      openBlaBlaOverlay();
    }
  });

  function openBlaBlaOverlay () {
    var blaBlaLink = document.querySelector('a[class="blabla-overlay"]');
    blaBlaLink.click();
  }
</script>
```

But that sounds somewhat complex. Any other/simpler ideas?

Comment: That doesn't really sound that complicated to me.  The high level design you presented seems like a pretty reasonable implementation for the requirements you have.  Does it feel complex to you because you don't know how to implement some of it?

Comment: The 3rd party overlay probably has some way of programmatically firing the control (I'm thinking it's a jquery plug in or similar), use that.

Comment: I actually have an implementation. But I don't have a strong background in vanilla JS. I had to spent some of my time working with frameworks so I might be under the assumption that there is a helper for everything. I also added some code for reference.

Checking if I can trigger the plugin manually might be another approach.

Comment: What is the purpose of the hidden link, why do you not just do `document.querySelector('a[class="blabla-overlay"]').click()` directly in the if block in your window load callback?

Comment: @CBroe Ah, good catch! Initial idea was to watch the url for changes and I wanted to prevent a click to cause the watcher to trigger another click and so on. I noticed that I can just check the url on window load but kept the hidden link.

Actually, this makes it a quite bit simpler! Do you mind posting my code from above as an answer (with the changes you proposed: dropping the hidden link/merging it into a single one and calling it directly)? I can accept that as an answer!

Comment: If you got the modified, working code already, you can post a self-answer, https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @CBroe, I made it a bit simpler:

```
<a class="blabla-overlay" href="#something" blabla-data-link="123abc">Click me for overlay!</a>

<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    if (window.location.hash === '#something') {
      document.querySelector('a[class="blabla-overlay"]').click();
    }
  });
</script>
```